# Ghostscript's pdfwrite to grayscale results in wrong graylevel

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, grayscale, pdf-conversion

I try to convert a PDF file (test.pdf, attached below) using Ghostscript (9.20 on Windows) to only use the Graylevel colorspace (not RGB or CMY):

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -dUseCIEColor -o gray.pdf -f test.pdf
```

The result indeed only uses gray colors:

```
>gswin64c.exe -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov gray.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.92673 CMYK OK
```

(I need to use -dUseCIEColor, otherwise CMY values are >0, this is a separate problem which I havent yet solved...)

My problem: The resulting gray.pdf uses significantly different graylevels than the original test.pdf (open in your PDF viewer and compare for yourself).

Does anyone see my mistake or what I should do differently to get the same PDF but in grayscale rather than RGB colorspace?

Thank you very much!

test.pdf: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzjatAIrG6P3S2F5Vng4cUhUS0U

gray.pdf: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzjatAIrG6P3cEtTY3JaaTJCS2c

Comment: Don't use -dUseCIEColor, you are embarking on a 2 step process which will undoubtedly produce the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a multiple conversion, and not managing the colour space conversions at all.

Firstly you convert the original colour into a CIEBased colour space (and the space varies depending on the number of components in the original space). Since you don't specify Colour Rendering Dictionaries, this is an uncontrolled conversion, you are using the defaults.

You then embark on another conversion from CIEBased (which cannot, in general, be represented in PDF anyway, so would **always** result in an additional conversion) into DeviceGray. Again you haven't supplied any ICC profiles for this conversion, so you are using the default ones.

If you insist on using -dUseCIEColor (which I would very strongly advise against, controlling this is hard) then you need to supply ColorRendering Dictionaries to control the conversion from device space into CIE space, and also ICC profiles to control the subsequent conversion from CIE space into DeviceGray.

But I strongly suspect that you will get better results by not using -dUseCIEColor, just like Ghostscript tells you.

Comment: Thank you very much, KenS!
I tried different things with ICC profiles, also creating my own ones, but didnt really succeed. My knowledge about these is limited. So I stay now with the slightly darker gray.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess about what you need based on source file. There's `DeviceRGB` 0.5/0.5/0.5 filled rectangle, and I suspect you want it to become 0.5 `DeviceGray`.

The solutions and speculations below will work for that and similar cases only. (E.g., I have no idea what are *"CMY values"* you write about, i.e. if there are `DeviceCMYK` or `ICC-based` or anything else in your files). There're simple formulas to convert between device color spaces (see **PDF Reference**), one of them indeed maps from equal values in `DeviceRGB` to same value in `DeviceGray`. To make it work, use `GhostScript` **9.10**:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dUseFastColor -o test_1.pdf -f test.pdf
```

Note the switch `-dUseFastColor`. You'll get "correct" 0.5 grayscale filled rectangle.

To make it work in versions **9.10** .. **9.20** (excluding both), I had to add another switch: `-dPDFUseOldCMS`. Again, 0.5 grayscale filled rectangle in result.

As last switch name indicates, simple things were probably considered deprecated, and looks like were scrapped in **9.20**.

Instead, new wonderful CMS engine was introduced (since **9.10**). Except, it doesn't work for high-level devices (`pdfwrite` included). Either switched off or broken, for many releases.

I was unable to make it work for any combination of device- or ICC-based colors in source and command line options, to make it actually use the `-sOutputICCProfile` option, for either `DeviceCMYK` or `DeviceGray` output (or ICC-based output, whatever). Same color values in produced files.

I'd appreciate if someone indicates I'm wrong and *shows* an opposite example.

It worked, actually (partly -- for device source colors only), in **9.10**:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -sOutputICCProfile=sgray.icc -o test_2.pdf -f test.pdf
```

Using different icc profiles results in different (and correct, it looks) output. To convert from equal RGB values to same Gray values one would need grayscale profile with same gamma as (default) `sRGB`. Just, use free `ICC Profile Inspector` to extract a curve from `sRGB` and import it into e.g. `sgray.icc` (distributed with `Ghostscript`).

The advantage of using a profile to convert RGB to Gray, preserving gamma, opposed to "simple formula" described above, may or may not be worth the effort. Check for your files and purposes.